# Twitter request with java connection fails

Tags: java, twitter

I can pull the user's statuses with no problem with cURL, but when I connect with Java, the xml comes out truncated and my parser wants to cry. I'm testing with small users so it's not choke data or anything.

```
public void getRuserHx(){
 System.out.println("Getting user status history...");

 String https_url = "https://twitter.com/statuses/user_timeline/" + idS.rootUser + ".xml?count=100&page=[1-32]";
 URL url;
 try {    
     url = new URL(https_url);
     HttpsURLConnection con = (HttpsURLConnection)url.openConnection(); 
     con.setRequestMethod("GET");
     con.setReadTimeout(15*1000);

     //dump all the content into an xml file
     print_content(con);

 } 
 catch (MalformedURLException e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
 } 
 catch (IOException e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
 }

 System.out.println("Finished downloading user status history.");
```

}

```
private void print_content(HttpsURLConnection con){
    if(con!=null){

    try {           
       BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));

          File userHx = new File("/" + idS.rootUser + "Hx.xml");
          PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(idS.hoopoeData + userHx);

           String input;        
           while ((input = br.readLine()) != null){
           out.println(input);
           }

       br.close();  
    } 
    catch (IOException e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

This request doesn't need auth. Sorry about my ugly code. My professor says input doesn't matter so my I/O is a trainwreck.

Comment: Are you sure your connection is made properly and got input for your program ?

Comment: Yeah, the xml is writing out, but the file is truncated (mid tag) at the same line each time. The file comes out fine if I use cURL from the command line. It seems that the connection with Java does not persist.

Comment: What happens if you remove setting the read timeout?

Comment: Removing the timeout didn't make any diff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to flush the output stream when you write the content out. Did you flush or close the output stream?

Comment: I added the code for the print method. I did close the BufferedReader, is that what you mean?

Comment: I added out.flush() and I've got it now I think. Thanks.